# OpenGL compute shader results in APPCRASH

Tags: opengl, glsl, compute-shader

Can anybody help check why this OpenGL compute shader results in APPCRASH on my Nvidia GT440, Windows 7 64bit? I want to learn about the memory order defined in GLSL, so I write this simple shader. I don't think there is any problem about the shader code.

The sizes of image0, image1 and output_image are all 1024x768. output_image is only used to check if the result is correct.

The work group size is 16x16. The number of work groups launched in the X/Y/Z dimension is 1024/16, 768/16 and 1, i.e. `glDispatchCompute(64, 48, 1)`. If x index of the invocation ID is even, it sets the pixel (x,y) of image0, then image1. If x index of the invocation ID is odd, it reads image1 and waits until the corresponding pixel (x-1, y) of image1 is set, then reads image0.

```
#version 450 core

layout (local_size_x = 16, local_size_y = 16) in;

layout (binding = 0, rgba8ui) uniform uimage2D output_image;

layout (binding = 1, r32ui) uniform volatile coherent uimage2D image0;
layout (binding = 2, r32ui) uniform volatile coherent uimage2D image1;

void main(void)
{
    // thread 0 of each work group clears a portion of output image
    if (gl_LocalInvocationIndex == 0) {
        uvec2 start = gl_WorkGroupSize.xy * gl_WorkGroupID.xy;

        for (uint j = start.y; j < start.y + gl_WorkGroupSize.y; ++j)
            for (uint i = start.x; i < start.x + gl_WorkGroupSize.x; ++i)
                imageStore(output_image, ivec2(i, j), uvec4(0));
    }

    barrier();

    if (gl_GlobalInvocationID.x % 2 == 0) {
        // store to image0, then image1
        imageStore(image0, ivec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy), uvec4(1));
        imageStore(image1, ivec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy), uvec4(1));
    }
    else {
        ivec2 coord = ivec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy) - ivec2(1, 0);

        // wait for image1 to be set
        uint flag;
        do {
            flag = imageLoad(image1, coord).x;
        }
        while (flag != 1);

        // check if image0 is set
        uint color = imageLoad(image0, coord).x * 255;

        // write output image
        imageStore(output_image, coord, uvec4(flag));
        imageStore(output_image, ivec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy), uvec4(color));
    }
}
```

Comment: Congratulation, you have just written undefined behavior which most likely will end up as an endless loop. You seem to be lacking the basic 101 of GPU architectures, and unfortunately, explaining them would be way too broad for a stackoverflow answer.

Comment: "*I want to learn about the memory order defined in GLSL, so I write this simple shader.*" That is not a good way to learn about the GLSL memory model. That will only tell you how NVIDIA works; it will say nothing about what GLSL allows.

Comment: @derhass, can you point out which part of this shader code has undefined behavior?

Comment: @NicolBolas, thanks. I have read the OpenGL and GLSL spec. I'm trying some examples to assure my understanding is correct.

Comment: The particular execution ordering of the compute shader invocations is undefined, unless you enforce some particular ordering by appropriate `barrier` commands (which can only happen in non-uniform control flow). You also assume that all CS vocations are able to progress indepenently of each other - but this is not true at all, a sub-group of threads is executed in lockstep, _sharing_ the control flow (a "warp" of 32 threads in NVidia's terminology).

Comment: (... continuing last comment) So, If one of your threads happens to get into the "wait loop" branch before the write branch of the  "neighboring" thread got executed, you are completely deadlocked because these two divergent branches can _never_ be executed in parallel on the GPU. In that scenario, _before_ all of the threads in the sub-group could enter the write branch, they would have to wait for all other invocations in the sub-group to finish the wait branch first, which is impossible.

Comment: Nvidia only recently added some features to their Volta architecture to better deal with such fain-grained synchronization, see chapter on independent thread scheduling in [this whitepaper](http://images.nvidia.com/content/volta-architecture/pdf/volta-architecture-whitepaper.pdf). However, the `_syncwarp` mechanism is Nvidia-Only and only available in Cuda, and so far not available in the GL.

Comment: @derhass, OpenGL red book version 9 (GL 4.5) example 11.13 is an errant example, which is **Simple Per-Pixel Mutex**. It uses `imageAtomicCompSwap` in a `do {} while()` loop to take a per-pixel lock to prevent simultaneous access to a shared resouce between pixel shader invocations corresponding to the same pixel coordinate. This leads me to my misunderstanding that shader invocations are able to progress independently of each other. Actually, this example results in APPCRASH too.